# Why videos are not downloading from Url via app in a Android Tablet?

Tags: android, download, storage

I could be able to Download the videos and save it on sd card. When user is downloading multiple times it will save it on sd card until it has a free space on Memory. When File size is larger and if there is no space on sd card then it will not save the downloaded files on sd card.

This is all working fine in my Emulator. Except I could not be able to play the video in an Emulator. But the Downloaded video files is saving with a time and mp4 fomats. I could be able to view the video files via pulling it into a Desktop.

It is playing and working fine. Also no exception is throwing and app is very clear and pretty fine. Then what is the problem here ?

This is my code:

```
playFromUrlButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
playFromUrlButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoSDcard.this, "Download Button is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DownloadFromUrl(url,"mp4");
        }
 private String DownloadFromUrl(String Url,String format) {
 InputStream bis = null;
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 String fileName="mmData_"+startTime+"."+format;
 try {
 URL url = new URL(Url);
/* Open a connection to that URL. */
                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                    ucon.connect();
                    size=ucon.getContentLength();
  directory= new File (path);
                    System.out.println("File Directory:"+directory);
                    if(!directory.exists())
                    {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                    }
  directory=new File(path+fileName);
/*
                     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                     */
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
 int current=0;
                    while ((current = bis.read(data)) != -1) 
                    {
                        fos.write(data, 0, current); 
                    }

         /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */

                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    bis.close();
 System.out.println("Returns path and File name:"+path+fileName);
                    return path+fileName;
            }
 catch (IOException e) 
            {
            Toast.makeText(VideoSDcard.this, "Exception"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("\n Exception while Downloading"+e.toString());

            try 
            {
                      fos.flush();
                      fos.close();
                      bis.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                  Toast.makeText(VideoSDcard.this, "Exception1"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return path+fileName;
            }
           }
```

My Logcat,

```
06-11 13:52:18.867: I/System.out(10469): Argument Url:http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4
06-11 13:52:18.877: I/System.out(10469): Download from URL:http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4
06-11 13:52:19.307: I/System.out(10469): AvailableExternalMemorySize:170567680
06-11 13:52:19.307: I/System.out(10469): FileSize-14514169:available-170567680
06-11 13:52:19.317: I/System.out(10469): AvailableExternalMemorySize:170567680
06-11 13:52:19.327: I/System.out(10469): Video path:/mnt/sdcard/MyVideo/
06-11 13:52:19.327: I/System.out(10469): File Directory:/mnt/sdcard/MyVideo
06-11 13:52:19.327: I/System.out(10469): Check : /mnt/sdcard/MyVideo/ : mmData_1370938938871.mp4
06-11 13:53:19.539: I/System.out(10469): Returns path and File name:/mnt/sdcard/MyVideo/mmData_1370938938871.mp4
```

Why is it not playing in Android Tablet?

Comment: So you are asking why your videos are not playing on your tablet, right?

Comment: Yeah, May be Internet breakage ?

Comment: First of all check if they are downloaded properly, without any error while saving the bytes to sd card. Second thing maybe the file settings/format are not supported by the device which you are using to test.

Comment: Downloading completely without any errors in sd card. Then whats the problem I dont understand seriously

Comment: Unfortunately, activity has stopped. It is showing me like this when Iam testing it in Tablet. But I could be able to run it in Emulator. In emulator after Downloading a file, toast is displaying like "No space on sd card so Exception" and then displaying URL also. I have used toast in try catch loop. plz anyone help/ suggest me !

Comment: put some code where it is happening and the exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31565/discussion-between-meena-rengarajan-and-android-developer)

Comment: please tell me what is the problem? I have uploaded a code now please see above code!

Comment: post the stacktrace from LogCat so I can see what is the problem and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing network activity on the main UI thread. If your tablet is running Android >=v12, it will throw an exception - your emulator probably works because it is < v12.

Blocking the main thread is bad, you should instead perform this download in a separate thread. The best option would probably be an IntentService, so that the download isn't tied to your activity.

If you block the main thread, the users experience is compromised (app will appear to freeze), and the system will 'Android Not Responding' (ANR) after 10 seconds